# AWS toolkit for Eclipse - installation problem

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services

I have a problem installing this AWS toolkit.
I am following the instructions here:
https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/

I keep getting this HTTP 301 message and it just doesn't proceed past that. Any ideas?

My Eclipse version is 4.9.0.

[image: problem]

Comment: That error indicates that a page has moved. It should handle it okay. Anyway, for me it resolves to this CloudFront distribution: `https://d26s2n2rcct4v5.cloudfront.net/` Try that instead. If that is still bad, try opening the normal URL in a web browser and see what happens. It should return an XML file.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I can see this xml file from your link. What should I do with it though, with this site.xml?

Comment: I think that's the page that Eclipse is looking for. Try using the URL I provided in place `https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/`. It should redirect to the same thing, except that your Eclipse is complaining about the redirect.